# Could not find or load main class Foo

Tags: java, maven

I have an Maven project with only this class:

[image]

This is `<build><plugin>` from pom.xml:

[image]

And this is tree of project:

[image]

I build this project with goal `assembly:single` and run it with command `java -jar name.jar`

The result is this error [image]

I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Have you checked that the generated manifest file in the jar looks ok?

Comment: try extracting jar, does it contain Tester in correct dir ?

Comment: In extracted jar I have only one folder `META-INF` with a file `MANIFEST.MF` and classes are missing. Why? It's not my first time when compile a maven project like this and succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call instead:

`mvn clean package`

It will generate required single jar with the `org.raul.teste.Tester` inside.

Calling `assembly:single` will generate `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` only in your case, if you will open/unzip the result jar file in this case you will see that compiled classes were not included.

Comment: `mvn clean package` in goals? P.S.: I'm using Eclipse. And why `assembly:single` generate only MANIFEST.MF in my case? I use this goal on bigger projects and succeed. Why now not?

Comment: @raul1ro, correct, you can select `package` goal instead of `assembly:single` from IDE too.

Comment: I get this error : https://i.imgur.com/y83ABcI.png . In settings at `java>installed jre` is selected folder with `jre`

Comment: @raul1ro, also you can call `mvn compile assembly:single` if you want to use exactly `assembly:single` goal. Good to include `clean` goal too with `compile` and `assembly:single`.

Comment: @raul1ro, please select _JDK_ instead. _JRE (Java Runtime Environment)_ is minimal JVM implementation to run Java programs, _JDK (Java Development Kit)_ is the thing need to be used during development.

Comment: same error even with `assembly:single` and `jdk` selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180571/discussion-between-marme1ad-and-raul1ro).

Comment: Was a problem with Eclipse. In terminal `mvn compile assembly:single` works and my jar now run perfectly. Thank you!